# problem with installing package transformr and animating plot in r

Tags: r, gganimate

I have a data frame named `df` and want to create an animated chart line.
here is my data frame and code for animating the plot.

```
co1<- tibble(age= c(10:14 ), pop=c(10,12,14,16,18), cn= c(10.1,12.1,14.25,16.09,18.3), country ="USA")
co2<- tibble(age= c(10:14 ), pop=c(10.5,12.6,14.5,16.5,18.5), cn= c(10.6,12.5,14.3,16.7,18.6), country ="brazil")
co3<- tibble(age= c(10:14 ), pop=c(10.9,12.9,14.9,16.9,18.9), cn= c(11.9,13.9,15.9,17.9,19.9), country ="niger")
df<- rbind(co1,co2,co3)


df <- pivot_longer(df, cols = c("pop", "cn"))

#plot
ggplot(df, aes(x = age, y = value, group = country, col = name)) + geom_line() + 
  labs(x = "age", y = "population") + transition_states(country, transition_length = 3, state_length = 0) + 
  ggtitle("country: {closest_state}") + 
  theme_bw()
```

but when I try to run the example provided, I get this error:

`Error in transform_path(all_frames, states[[i]], ease, nframes[i], !!id, : transformr is required to tween paths and lines`

following some questions I have tried to install package `transformr` and  `devtools::install_github("thomasp85/transformr")` but both did not work and I got this error :

```
Warning in install.packages :
  downloaded length 2292878 != reported length 3644763
Warning in install.packages :
  URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/sf_1.0-1.tar.gz': Timeout of 60 seconds was reached
Error in download.file(url, destfile, method, mode = "wb", ...) : 
  download from 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/sf_1.0-1.tar.gz' failed
Warning in install.packages :
  download of package ‘sf’ failed
```

Answer (score 1):

The error messages indicate that there is an issue with installing the `sf` package. It looks like the CRAN mirror (https://cran.rstudio.com/) you are using is not responding. This might be a temporary issue.

You can try to select another mirror with `chooseCRANmirror()` or specify another mirror just to install the sf package:

```
install.packages('sf', repos='http://cran.us.r-project.org')
```

If that works try again to run `devtools::install_github("thomasp85/transformr")`.

Comment: thanks @Till but I got this error :`configure: error: gdal-config not found or not executable.
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘sf’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/sf’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘sf’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
 ‘/private/var/folders/2z/p2v9k6gs13b0sfncbxl9yp2r0000gn/T/RtmpzfNkWc/downloaded_packages’`

Comment: As the error message points out, your system seems to be missing the `gdal-config` binary. You need to make sure that it is installed before trying to install the sf package. On ubuntu you'd install it with this command `sudo apt-get install libgdal-dev` in the system terminal.

Comment: I did that in terminal `apt-get: command not found`

Comment: What operating system are you using? That command would only work on Ubuntu or derivatives of it.

Comment: I am using mac.

Comment: See [here](https://r-spatial.github.io/sf/#macos) for instructions on how to install the `sf` package and its prerequisite `gdal` on macOS.